# keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate (again)

Tags: java, ssl-certificate

My reward in this life for past deeds is to provide admin for some very ancient applications running on Java 1.7 (mostly 1.7.0_79). After the last round of certificate updates the applications stopped talking to the CAS auth server (couldn't validate the CA cert). Unfortunately when I try to install the [current CA certs](https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/), I get:

```
[root@example.com bin]# ./keytool -import -alias isrgrootx1 -file ~/isrg-root-x1-cross-signed.pem -keystore ../jre/lib/security/cacerts
Enter keystore password:
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate
```

Openssl on the same box (CentOS 5.11) has no issue reading the file (4096 bit RSA + sha256). And I did check that the file contained only a single certificate. I've seen a number of posts here about the same error message:

- DER format [does not apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535082/input-not-an-x-509-certificate-not-working-even-after-converting-to-der)
- It's [not a JKS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48496570/openssl-keytool-error-java-lang-exception-input-not-an-x-509-certificate)
- It's [not a CSR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988937/error-in-importing-certificate)
- It does not have an extra blank line at the end

Is this the end of the road or is there a way I can convince this version of Java to accept this certificate?

Comment: bypass the validation in your code until you find the solution. Not safe, but no headaches neither

Comment: Curiously I was already googling how to do that when you commented - unfortunately not yet finding a solution. Any pointers?

Comment: https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/aoD